# Modify Donut Chart Slices in C3/D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have created a simple donut chart using c3.js. Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aegmL7r0/).

If you hover over a slice of the Donut it will stick out. I was wondering if it is possible for the slice to stick out by default without hovering over.

For example i want slice A, slice B, and C to stickout by default How can I do that?

Here is my Code

```
var currentSlice;

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        columns: [
            ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06'],
            ['A', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['B', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50],
            ['C', 50, 100, 130, 240, 200, 150],
            ['D', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50],
            ['E', 130, 150, 200, 300, 200, 100]
        ],
        type: 'donut',
        onclick: function (e) {

        },
        onmouseover: function (d, i) {
            if(currentSlice !== void 0) {
                'currentSlice'.attr("transform","scale(1)")
            }

            currentSlice = d3.select(i).attr("transform", "scale(1.1)");


        },
        onmouseout: function (d, i) {

        }
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d',
                centered: true,
                position: 'inner-right'
            }
        }
    },
    bindto: '#dash',
    bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
        }

    },
    pie: {
        expand: true,
    },
    tooltip: {
        grouped: false,
        contents: function (data, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
            //  console.log("Containt");
            // console.log(data, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color);
            return "<p style='border:1px solid red;'>" + data[0].value + "</p>";

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setTimeout() to scale specific slices, once the chart is rendered.  Here's one way:

```
setTimeout( function() {
  d3.selectAll('.c3-arc-A, .c3-arc-B, .c3-arc-C').attr("transform", "scale(1.2)");       
}, 5);
```

Place this call after your `c3.generate()` call.

Answer (score 2):

c3js has two options, but both require a slight hack with 'setTimeout' to force our default scaling to happen *after* rendering and animation occur.

1. The `onrendered` function is available to set within the c3config object that one initializes the chart with. This function is triggered after a redraw is triggered but *before* visual rendering happens in the DOM. However, there is a hack to use `setTimeout` since it will create a separate callstack that will execute *after* the current callstack which in c3 happens to include redrawing the graph. ([explanation of setTimeout to force logic to run *after* current callstack executes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371202/4375502))
2. The `load` function exposes a `done` callback that is triggered *after* the elements are rendered to the DOM but *before* the animation finishes. So if one sets the initial scale transform in done, if the animations triggered by load are using the scale transform (which loading a pie chart appears to do), then the last keyframe of the animation will overwrite your modified scale back to `scale(1)`. However, we can similarly use `setTimeout` to run our code `after` the current callstack (which includes animation) executes.

In exploring this, I created a generalized form of rby's answer, and I offer two alternative paths to setting default scales through the `onrendered` and `done` functions exposed in c3. ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ggamir/a09y53dd/)):

```
var selected = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var _ARC = '.c3-arc';
var _SCALING = '1.1';

function getCurrentlySelected() {
  var _PREFIX = _ARC + '-';
  return d3.selectAll(_PREFIX + selected.join(', ' + _PREFIX));
}
```

Within c3config object and `onrendered` through initialization:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: { ... },
    onrendered: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          if (selected.length > 0) {
            getCurrentlySelected().attr('transform', 'scale(' + _SCALING + ')');
          }
        }); // Notice we don't need a delay, just taking advantage to force our logic to happen after current callstack is executed
    }
});
```

Also possible to use `load` with `done` after initialization:

```
chart.load({
  columns: [
    ['A', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
    ['B', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50],
    ['C', 50, 100, 130, 240, 200, 150],
    ['D', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50],
    ['E', 130, 150, 200, 300, 200, 100]
  ],
  done: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (selected.length > 0) {
        getCurrentlySelected().attr('transform', 'scale(' + _SCALING + ')');
      }
    }) // Notice we don't need a delay, just taking advantage to force our logic to happen after current callstack is executed
  }
});
```